# Homotopy orbits, spectra and infinite loop spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy, loop-spaces

Let $X$ be an (naive) $O(n)$-spectrum (I'm choosing to work with orthogonal spectra). I've recently come across the following results,

$$(S^{n-1} \wedge X)_{hO(n)} \simeq X_{hO(n-1)}$$

and

$$\Omega^\infty (X_{hG)}) \simeq (\Omega^\infty X)_{hG} $$

where $G$ is a compact Lie group.

I've spent the last few days trying to find sources for these results - and trying to prove them myself to little avail.

Any help/suggestions or references would be greatly appreciated.

---

**Added** The answer by Tyler has shown that the second is false. This raises the question about how close can we get, in the following sense:
If $X$ is $n$-connected, then how connected is the map
$$ 
(\Omega^\infty X)_{hG} \to \Omega^\infty(X_{hG})\,?
$$

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Both of these are false.

The first is close to true: if $S(n-1)$ is the unit sphere in $\Bbb R^{n}$ with its standard $O(n)$-action, then we can identify $S(n-1)$ with $O(n) / O(n-1)$ and so get the identification
$$
(S(n-1)_+ \wedge X)_{hO(n)} = EO(n)_+ \wedge_{O(n)} O(n)/O(n-1)_+ \wedge X = EO(n)_+ \wedge_{O(n-1)} X.
$$

---

To show that the first one is false, let's take $X = \Sigma^\infty O(n)_+$. Then the first equation would give an equivalence between $\Sigma^\infty S^{n-1}$ and $\Sigma^\infty O(n)/O(n-1)_+ \cong \Sigma^\infty S(n-1)_+$. These have nonisomorphic homology for all $n$.

For the second one, we can take $X$ to be the desuspension of the Eilenberg-MacLane spectrum $H\Bbb Z$ with trivial $O(n)$-action. Then $\Omega^\infty X$ is contractible and so its homotopy orbit space is $BG$ (or contractible, if you use the based orbit space), while
$$
\begin{align*}
\pi_n \Omega^\infty (\Sigma^{-1} H\Bbb Z)_{hG}
&= \pi_n (\Sigma^{-1} H\Bbb Z_{hG})\\
&= \pi_{n+1} (H\Bbb Z_{hG})\\
&= \pi_{n+1} (H\Bbb Z \wedge \Sigma^\infty BG_+)\\
&= H_{n+1}(BG, \Bbb Z)
\end{align*}
$$
which is typically very different from either $\pi_n BG$ or $\pi_n (*)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For the second one, can we make some kind of connectivity argument, say for instance the spectrum in $n$-connected. Can we say anything about the connectivity of either side and get a result about the connectivity of the canonical map between them? (The canonical map here will go from right to left) - This argument won't give an equivalence but it's not a bad partial result

Comment: @274072 Yes. I believe that if X is n-connected, the map is (2n+1)-connected. (It is the same as the connectivity estimate for the map $\Sigma^\infty \Omega^\infty X \to X$.) For this, you need to use based homotopy orbits.

Comment: On second thought, that should probably be 2n+2.

Comment: I think (2n+1)-connected would be correct if we took X to be a suspension spectrum of a based space... albeit I’m not convinced - I’m obtuse when it comes to connect arguments